# What metrics to use for Kafka failures in request handling?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to visualize Kafka metrics that can help me gain better insights to failures in the Kafka Server level while handling requests.

While looking at the various metrics in JMX, I can see following two metrics:

1. FailedProduceRequestsPerSec
2. FailedFetchRequestsPerSec

When I visualize the metrics in my production system, I can see that for the past 60 days, both these metrics show values of 0.

I suspect if this is the case since we had a couple of incidents where there was an increase in the failures while reading or publishing?

Could someone verify If these metrics are still available? Quick googling or search are not giving any conclusive answers. I am using Kafka version 0.9.0.1.

Another question on similar term, are there some metrics that can help in visualizing failures for other types of requests like (Metadata)